# Mapstruct не проставляет текущую дату

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

класс с маппером

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", imports = {LocalDateTime.class})
public interface ManualExcelMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "updateDateTime", expression = "java(LocalDateTime.now())")
    List<ManualCurrency> mapExcelCurrencyToEntity(List<ExcelCurrency> source);
```

на выходе в сущностях ManualCurrency поля updateDateTime nullы. не понятно почему мапстракт не реализует expression = "java(LocalDateTime.now())"

Answer (score 0):

нужно было прописать маппер для одной сущности

```
@Mapping(target = "updateDateTime", expression = "java(LocalDateTime.now())")
    ManualCurrency mapExcelCurrencyToEntity(ExcelCurrency source);
    List<ManualCurrency> mapExcelCurrencyToEntity(List<ExcelCurrency> source);
```